# Get value (String) of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I know it's simple question, but in

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> collection;
ArrayList<String> listOfSomething;

collection= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
listOfSomething = new ArrayList<String>();

listOfSomething.Add("first");
listOfSomething.Add("second");
collection.Add(listOfSomething);
listOfSomething.Clear();
listOfSomething.Add("first");
collection.Add(listOfSomething);
```

I want to take String from ArrayList of ArrayList, and I don't know how to do that. For example I go

```
ArrayList<String> myList = collection.get(0); 
String s = myList.get(0);
```

and it works! but:

## Big update:

```
private List<S> valuesS;
private List<Z> valuesZ;


ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfS;
ArrayList<String> listOfZ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Zdatasource = new ZDataSource(this);
        Zdatasource.open();
        valuesZ = Zdatasource.getAllZ();
        
        Sdatasource = new SDataSource(this);
        Sdatasource.open();
        valuesS = Sdatasource.getAllS();

        List<Map<String, String>> groupData 
             = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData 
             = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

        listOfS = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        listOfZ = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (S i : valuesS) { // S is class
            for (Z j : valuesZ) { // Z is class
                if(j.getNumerS().equals(i.getNumerS())) {
                    listOfZ.add(j.getNumerZ());
                }
                else
                {
                    //listOfZ.add("nothing");
                }
            }
                listOfS.add(listOfZ);
                if(!listOf.isEmpty()) listOfZ.clear();
        }



@Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
            int childPosition, long id) {
        try
        {       
            ArrayList<String> myList = listOfS.get(groupPosition); 
            String s = myList.get(childPosition);
         PrintToast("group "+Integer.toString(groupPosition)+", child "+Integer.toString(childPosition) + " , "+ s);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("FS", e.toString());
        } 
        return true;
    }
```

return me java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
when I click on item which really should exist. I didn't show code which generate ListView, but I can tell you that my listOfS contains 3 items:
first is Null listOfZ, second listOfZ got 2 elements, third listOfZ got 1 element.

Comment: You get null on which call - to myList or to String s?

Comment: If you got null, it means the second element of the first list in the collection is null. How could we help?

Comment: Well I am going to update my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
listOfSomething.Clear();
listOfSomething.Add("first");
collection.Add(listOfSomething);
```

You are clearing the list here and adding one element ("first"), the 1st reference of `listOfSomething` is updated as well sonce both reference the same object, so when you access the second element `myList.get(1)` (which does not exist anymore) you get the null.

Notice both `collection.Add(listOfSomething);` save two references to the same arraylist object.

You need to create two different instances for two elements:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> collection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> listOfSomething1 = new ArrayList<String>();
listOfSomething1.Add("first");
listOfSomething1.Add("second");

ArrayList<String> listOfSomething2 = new ArrayList<String>();
listOfSomething2.Add("first");

collection.Add(listOfSomething1);    
collection.Add(listOfSomething2);
```

Comment: Yes. Correct. I use listOfZ = new ArrayList<String>(); instead of listOfZ.clear();

Answer (score 11):

Because the **second element is null** after you clear the list.

Use:

```
String s = myList.get(0);
```

And remember, **index 0 is the first element**.

Comment: Yes that was true, but I write down example code and I make stupid mistake.

Answer (score 5):

The right way to iterate on a list inside list is:

```
//iterate on the general list
for(int i = 0 ; i < collection.size() ; i++) {
    ArrayList<String> currentList = collection.get(i);
    //now iterate on the current list
    for (int j = 0; j < currentList.size(); j++) {
        String s = currentList.get(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner way of iterating the lists is:

```
// initialise the collection
collection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
// iterate
for (ArrayList<String> innerList : collection) {
    for (String string : innerList) {
        // do stuff with string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have String array like this
We have to pass data through response.body.getdata and this data pass in constructor like this,

List taginnerData;

 "data": [
                "banana",
                "apple",
                "grapes",
                "Pears",
                "Mango",
                "Cherry",
                "Guava",
                "TorontoVsMilwaukee_12Jan19"
            ]

 String[] myArray = new String[taginnerData.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < taginnerData.size(); i++) {
            myArray[i] = String.valueOf(taginnerData.get(i));
            holder.tv_channel_name.setText("" +taginnerData.get(i));
//we get any value from here to set in adapter
        }
```